# Backslash n "\n" doesn't work?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

Hello I am making an application to split the song text based on certain char. The application works when I type something such as "sampletext/ sampletext", then the result should be :

```
sampletext 
sampletext
```

but, instead of above, the result is

```
sampletextsampletext
```

Below is the code :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "";
        string[] a = TextToSongFormatConverter(textBox1.Text, '/');
        textBox2.Text += "\n"; textBox2.Text += "\n"; textBox2.Text += "\n";
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            textBox2.Text += item;
            textBox2.Text += "\n";
        }
    }

    public static string[] TextToSongFormatConverter(string text, char separator)
    {
        string[] result;
        result = text.Split(separator);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = result[i].Trim();
        }
    }
```

I am using visual studio 2012 and c# and windows form :

This is the screenshoot :
[image]

Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Environment.NewLine` instead. It will give you proper new line characters for system your program is running on.

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.
>
> *from [`Environment.NewLine` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

Comment: wow. i can't believe that barely know `Environment.NewLine` in my last semester of IT university. Thanks.

Comment: @MosesAprico You don't have to know how it' called. You should know how to look for things like that within the documentation. btw. does it work with `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: I mean, the only way to do a new line, before this, I only know `\n` and yeah that works just fine. Going to accept your answer, but there's 6 minutes restriction left.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)